# I am getting the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template-form

I have tried other solutions such as fixing form references but that didn't help me. Here is my form for a login

```
    <form [formGroup]="longinForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="name" >Username</label>
        <input type="text" name ="user" [(ngModel)]="loginuserdata.user" 
 #user="ngModel" 
        class="form-control" required >
        <div *ngIf="submitted">
        <div [hidden]="user.valid || user.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          Username is required
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="pass" >Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="pass" [(ngModel)]="loginuserdata.pass" #pass="ngModel"
        class="form-control"  required >
        <div *ngIf="submitted">
        <div [hidden]="pass.valid || pass.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            Password is required
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

also here is my login component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { ILoginData } from './login-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginform',
  templateUrl: './loginform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginform.component.css']
})
export class LoginformComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm:FormGroup;
  loginuserdata : any[] = [];
  error:string;

  submitted=false;

  constructor(private route: Router,private service:LoginService) { }

  get f(){return this.loginForm.controls;}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onSubmit();
  }

  onSubmit(){

    if(this.loginForm.invalid){return;}//form invalid stop here
    //form is valid do something
    this.submitted=true;
    if(this.f.user.value == "Admin" && this.f.pass.value == "Apassword"){
    this.service.getAdmin()
    .subscribe(data => this.loginuserdata = data)
              this.route.navigateByUrl('admin');
              err => this.error = err;
              console.log(this.error);
    }

  }

}
```

If you guys need to see any other pieces of my code let me know please help me out I tried something similar to an answer solved to this but it didn't work for me.

Comment: why calling ` this.onSubmit();` inside `ngOnInit() `

Comment: where are you initiating your form ?

Comment: I took this.onSubmit() out of ngOnInit(). Which fixed that error actually thanks btw but then I still get this error now. ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: `[formGroup]="loginForm"`

Comment: also to answer @NadhirFalta I don't think I am initiating it anywhere should I? when you say initiating you mean like <app-loginform></app-loginform> right?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar should I just get rid of that and use #form="ngForm"?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar getting rid of it actually fixed that issue as well. Now when I make believe I am going to submit I get this error. LoginformComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined. when clicking on it it points to this line <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">. Can you or anyone else help me with this as well? Sorry for all the questions I am completely new to angular still. Thanks

Comment: @Anthony You are mixing `ReactiveForms` and `TemplateForms`. Stick to one https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the form controls, you have it defined but you need something like the following. You need to initialise the form group.

```
import { NgForm, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'; 

//Be sure to import formBuilder and inject through constructor. This will allow you 
//to manage how you will build the form and add validation.
//Its a helper class provided by Angular to help us explicitly declare forms.

constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ){}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

This is where you can define the controls and the validators for the form group. (This example would just dictate that there needs to be a value for each in order to be valid. This should be built in the `ngOnInit`.

Then in your template you can remove the `[(ngModel)]` and make it look like the following. The value for the input will then be held within the control when you need to access it.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" name ="user" [formControlName]="'username'" 
  class="form-control" required>
<form>
```

Above would serve as an example for the login username / email.
Also as mentioned in the comments you have a typo in the form in the HTML.

This should then be valid when you are trying to access the `valid` and `invalid` properties of the from group. Comment if you have any trouble.

[Here is the Angular documentation for reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: OK thanks Ill give that a try and let you know if it works

Comment: Also its worth mentioning what is `formBuilder` here

Comment: A good way to check would be to populate the input and submit the form, then add console.log(this.loginForm) at the start of your submit function. You can then check for the value of the control to ensure it is coming through. Amit Chigadani, please suggest and edit or I will add more info shortly :-)

Comment: hey @dince12 on my component here is my new change   ngOnInit() {
   this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl(''),
    });
  } 
then onSubmit(){console.log(this.loginForm.value)} I get this error LoginformComponent.html:2 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}} also before I submit I still get this error as well LoginformComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. Not sure why as I am following the documentation you sent.

Comment: Sorry check the edit, you need to bring in formBuilder and have something like     this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required] });

Comment: Yea I fixed those typos actually but now when I try submitting to the console I still get this error. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined which then points to this <app-loginform></app-loginform>

Comment: in html change to this [formControlName]=" 'username' " , needs to be passed as as a string

Comment: Hey sorry I just keep getting errors after errors lol I fixed all that now I have this issue ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined. Also my console.log still doesn't print the values.

Comment: Im not sure how to create a chat, would probably be the best way to try and help you.

Comment: It said something about not enough reps to create a chat do you want to see my template code and component code now? I just didn't paste it before with the error because there was too many characters

Comment: @dince12 template   <form [formGroup]="longinForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="username" >Username</label>
        <input type="text" name ="user" [formControlName]="'username'" class="form-control" required >
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="password" >Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="pass" [formControlName]="'password'" class="form-control"  required >
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: @dince12 component pretty much can't paste the whole thing or it too long 

loginForm:FormGroup;
  loginuserdata : any[] = [];
  error:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]});
  }

onSubmit(){
console.log(this.loginForm.value)
}

Comment: @dince12 I finally got it working with no errors thanks for your help in the beginning though didn't realize I needed form controls.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do this.

`ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.onSubmit()
  }`

I think it was not yet defined at ngOninit.
Check Life Cycle.